# Google API + Service Account for impersonate user

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-workspace

What I'm traing to do is to get all the members of a single group, and then download all the emails headers they have in gmail. To do this I started with google gmail api and members api, but i get stuck. I realice that I can't do it even if I have admin role.

What i found is that the right way to do it (I think...) is to use a service account for impersonate user. What i done:

1. Create a new project.
2. Create service account credentials.
3. Add Domain-wide Delegation to the service account.
4. Enable scopes for this proyect.

The code to create the service:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests
import json

class Service:

    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/',
            'https://sites.google.com/feeds',
            'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/activity',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata'
            ]

    secret_file = 'client-secret.json'
    service = ''
    service_name = ''
    service_version = ''
    delegated_credentials = ''
    credentials = ''

    def __init__(self, servicename, serviceversion):
        self.service_name = servicename
        self.service_verion = serviceversion
        self.newService()

    def newService(self):
        self.credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self.secret_file, scopes=self.SCOPES)
        self.credentials = self.credentials.with_subject('admin@domain.com')
        self.service = build(self.service_name, self.service_verion, credentials=self.credentials)
        return self.service

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Members class:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from service import Service
import requests
import json

class Members:

    service = ''
    group_name = ''
    members = []

    def __init__(self, groupname):
        self.group_name = groupname
        self.service = Service('admin', 'directory_v1')

    def get_members(self):
        print('Buscando los miembros del grupo')
        results = self.service.service.members().list(groupKey=self.group_name).execute()
        for member in results['members']:
            print('Descargando datos de: ', member['email'])
            self.members.append(member['id'])

        return self.members


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

app.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from members import Members
from user import User
from service import Service
import requests


def main():

    member = Members("group@ldomain.com")
    members_list = member.get_members()

    for member in members_list:
        print(member)
        user = User(member)
        messages = user.get_user_inbox()
        user.get_message_info(messages)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I have:

> "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method,
>   or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."